# Access component instance from vue watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, watch, computed-properties

I'm working on a project, similar as a bill manager, so I want that the subtotal get recalculated every time that quantity or unit value change, I have tried and searched to accomplish this using watcher or computed properties, but I don't find the right approach, cause I need to access the whole scope of the element when another change, like this.

Model structure:

- detail
- quantity
- unit value
- subtotal (should be a computed or updated)

So I think I should be able of doing something like this:

```
    Vue.component('item', {
    template: '#item',
    props: {
      item: Object,
    },
    computed:{
        total: function(){ 
            return this.quantity*this.unit_value;
         }
    },
    watch:{
      'item.quantity':()=>{
        this.subtotal = this.quantity*this.unit_value;
      }
    }
  });
```

*I have several components being read from a list*

I merged the approach using watcher and computed in the same code to make it shorter.

The problem is that I haven't found a way to access the hole element from inside itself, anyone could pls explain the right way? thanks

Comment: " I haven't found a way to access the hole element from inside itself, " .. what do you mean by that? What do you want to access and where

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't use arrows functions there, use method declarations.

If you want to watch for a property of the `item` object, you'll have to watch for the `item` object itself, and additionally use the `deep: true` flag of the watcher.

Final detail, you are using several properties that are not declared in your `data`. Declare them, otherwise they will not be reactive, that is, the computed will not recalculate when they change.

See code:

```js
Vue.component('item', {
  template: '#item',
  props: {
    item: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      subtotal: null,         // added data properties
      quantity: null,
      unit_value: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    total: function() {
      return this.quantity * this.unit_value;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    item: {                          // watching for item now
      deep: true,                    // using deep: true
      handler() {                    // and NOT using arrow functions
        this.subtotal = this.quantity * this.unit_value;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response.I modify it into that way, and the watcher doesn't even trigger when I change some property :/